# Monitor in C++ - Linux

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I an new at working with IPC objects with synchronization purposes for processes and threads.

Is there any special way to implement a Monitor in C? (such as semaphores, pipes, sockets, etc.) Is there a special .h file that has a specific object to use here?

If not, which is the best way to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Silvio.

Comment: Linux certainly supports all of the above (semaphores, pipes, and sockets), so it's mostly a question of deciding which really applies to the problem(s) you need to solve.

Comment: Why is your question header talking about C++ but your question body and tags about C? Which language do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use select, it works pretty much for everything you need: http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Beyond that, I usually use the pthread style functions for mutexes/semaphores, but it's really down to what the task at hand actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be a separate process. When a process starts it registers this fact to the monitor process. Then the monitor process can use calls to check if the process that registered with it is still running

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your scenario but my guess is you want something that requires very little setup to implement is which case I'd go with septical.